# Transform.position differs in code and editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to set my player's position to an cube's position in my scene.

I do this using the following function, which gets called when the object is selected:

```c#
public void PickCube ()
{
    Debug.Log(this.gameObject.transform.position); //this is different from the values in the editor
    Player p = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player").GetComponent<Player> ();
    p.SetPosition (gameObject.transform.position); //put the player at this cube
}
```

However, my cubes position in the scene is different from the position I'm attempting to get via gameObject.transform.position:

This is the position I see in the editor:

[image]

This is the position returned by Debug.Log:

```
(25.0, -6.9, 20.5)
```

Why am I getting different positions in the editor and code?
I looked into global vs local position, and `gameObject.transform.position.normalized`, but neither of these were the problem or solution.

Update:

When I do `Debug.Log(gameObject.name)`, it returns the name of the script "LevelCube". I thought gameObject was supposed to be the object the script is attached to?

Comment: what is setPosition?

Comment: Does your object have parent, if it have then use localPosition. Also as mentioned by Mohammad what does SetPosition method do?

Comment: There is a difference between transform.position and transform.localPosition.

Local position is relative to the parent, and I believe this is what shows up in the inspector. 

Try using localPosition or make sure that your gameObject has no parents.

Comment: My object does not have a parent that I'm aware of. And SetPosition is in my Player class. It sets my player's position at the object's position: this.transform.position = v; (where v is a Vector3).

Comment: using `gameObject` or `this` is redundant. Just do `transform.position`. Is it neccesary to do it using `SetPosition`? Could you instead also directly set the position on the Player GameObject without that component? (`GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform.position = transform.position`)

Comment: I also see you have a copy `InvertedSphere(1)` ..  is it possible that the same component is attached there and you see that output instead?

Answer (score 1):

1.) Just use (this).transform.position rather than your function

2.) If problem persists, try transform.localPosition instead

Comment: 1. My function outputs this.transform.position to the console log. It's output differs from that in my editor. 2. localPosition returns the same output.

Comment: transform.localPosition is giving the same value as in the editor, thanks